# How to have mypy ignore classes using a specific decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, python-typing

Sometimes as a syntactic convenience, I define class decorators that turn class definitions into data rather than a new class. Or they return the class that was passed in almost entirely unchanged, except for adding one field containing the data that was generated from the class definition.

However when I do this I am often annotating fields with objects that are not real types. For example:

```
@turn_into_data
class Foo:
    bar: 5
```

This might build a dictionary `{ "bar" : 5 }`. `5` is not a type in Python. If I also typecheck my code with `mypy` or `pytype` they will error here. There is a standard workaround:

```
@turn_into_data
@typing.no_type_check
class Foo:
    bar: 5
```

But this has to be repeated every time I use `@turn_into_data`. I can't just have `turn_into_data` call it because the type checker isn't actually running either decorator, it just special cases seeing `typing.no_type_check` in the decorator list and disables checking in that case.

I could change all my type annotations so that instead of `bar: 5` I write `bar: Annotated[Any, 5]`. `Annotated` was introduced as a way to introduce extra data in an annotation that isn't strictly for type checking. But this is much more verbose. Again there's the temptation to try to define my decorator to work around it, having it wrap the declared type in `Annotated[Any, T]` but again by then it's already too late, the static checker doesn't know about the transformation.

Is there any way to say my decorator should also disable type checking?

Comment: This looks like you're recreating the built-in `@dataclass`.

Comment: If not, why not do it the way it does: `bar = 5`. Don't abuse the type notation for this.

Comment: @Barmar not exactly. `@dataclass` takes a class and returns a class. `@turn_into_data` takes a class and returns a dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar Because I'm using this to make nicer syntax for making bindings for structs/types in another lang. So confusingly I am trying to generate data that represents type information, just not Python type information :)

Comment: I still don't understand what is wrong with doing `bar = 5` and adjusting `turn_into_data` to build a dict from values instead of annotations. Your MRE does not explain such necessity and sounds like an XY-problem. There is no way to "propagate" `no_type_check` from the custom decorator to the decorated class.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike It would prevent both having an annotation and a default value

Comment: "5 is not a type in Python". It's not a type, but it can be annotated `typing.Literal[5]`

Comment: "@turn_into_data takes a class and returns a dictionary." So where do you assign the result then?

Comment: @PawełRubin just like any other decorator, the result is in the old name. In the example above after running Foo is a dictionary without needing to do anything extra

Comment: No, the question @PawełRubin asks is "where do you put both annotation and default value, if you're building a dictionary". Not "where is the resulting dictionary created", but "what are the contents of that dictionary".

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike Ah. To keep the example simple I omitted but there's lots of possibilities. It could be the dictionary is from name (string) to a tuple of the type object and the default value.

Comment: This is a non-answer. You could do exactly the same thing by just assigning `bar = 5, "some value"`. The same possibilities, but without misusing Python's type annotation syntax. Don't get me wrong, sometimes you just want to do weird stuff. That's OK. But, if this is so important to you, you should probably write your own Mypy Plugin.

Comment: But I am with @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike: This smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg My goal is to have users be able to use a sane syntax consistent with the rest of python for being able to specify classes with members with types, but where the classes actually represent classes in a different lang. This means the objects I was planning to put in type annotation position were not normal python type objects, even though from a user perspective they fill that purpose.